# Translation check of "Through Empire comes Peace" and "Power of the Emperor"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

I have a title, "Power of the Emperor" and motto "Through Empire comes Peace" that I am translating to classical Latin. I'm fairly confident of the vocabulary choices but less so of my conjugations and declensions. I have the following for both:

- Per Imperium Pace Veniam
- Imperator Potestatis

I think the title is probably correct, but I'm not sure about the motto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your title now says '(The) Emperor of (the) Power': it should be 'Potestas Imperatoris'. Your motto now says 'Through (the) Empire I will Come by Peace': it should be 'Per Imperium Venit Pax'.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate including translations of what I originally had.

Answer (score 2):

I would change your title to "Potens (est) Imperator." This translates as "Powerful/Capable (is) (the) Emperor." I like this translation better because Latin prefers adjectives to genitives (as far as I can tell) and succinctness.

As Jasper has answered, "Per Imperium Venit Pax" is a good way of declining your motto.